# Center LinearLayout, itself containing layouts, on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble centering a layout on the screen. In particular, all is centered horizontally, but not vertically. Both the Table and the Linear  are too high, and there is too much space between the Table and the Linear. There are a few questions on StackO discussing similar problems, and I've tried various things suggested in these, but no joy. Currently, it looks like this: [image] Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|bottom">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/radiobuttonsTableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answerstatus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkmarkorx"
            android:src="@drawable/bluearrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton1Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/radiobuttonGroup1"
            android:src="@drawable/radiobuttonimage" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton1a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton1a" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton1b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton1b" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton1c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton1c" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <!-- empty column -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answerstatus2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkmarkorx"
            android:src="@drawable/bluearrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton2Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/radiobuttonGroup2"
            android:src="@drawable/radiobuttonimage" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton2a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton2a" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton2b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton2b" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton2c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton2c" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- spacer row -->

    <TableRow android:layout_margin="20dp" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/radiobuttonsTableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answerstatus3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkmarkorx"
            android:src="@drawable/bluearrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton3Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/radiobuttonGroup3"
            android:src="@drawable/radiobuttonimage" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton3a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton3a" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton3b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton3b" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton3c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton3c" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <!-- empty column -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answerstatus4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkmarkorx"
            android:src="@drawable/bluearrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton4Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/radiobuttonGroup4"
            android:src="@drawable/radiobuttonimage" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton4a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton4a" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton4b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton4b" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton4c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton4c" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1CheckButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbutton"
        android:onClick="clickCheck"
        android:src="@drawable/check" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1Step"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game1step1"
        android:onClick="clickCheck" />
    <!--  
        android:src="@drawable/step1" />
```

-->

UPDATE:
The suggestions are to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. So with this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    >
```

The `Table` and the `Linear` are centered on the screen *individually*, that is the `Linear` is on top of the `Table`. RelativeLayout seems to be the right way to go, and though the dipslay is still not right, I think that's separate issue.

UPDATE 2:
Ended up using LinearLayout with weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All should be inside a **RelativeLayout** container, with the LinearLayout fixed to parentBottom and the TableLayout positioned above it (first create the LinearLayout, or the TableLayout won't see it) and anchored to parentTop.

**[EDIT]**

OR ELSE:

You could use a **LinearLayout** as the outer container and then set weights for yout TableLayout and your inner LinearLayout (let's say 80 and 20 - adjust them as you like the proportion better).
In this case, you can maintain the original order.
Just remember to set the layout_width of both inner layouts to **0dp**, or layout_weight won't do it's magic.

Comment: When you say to first create the LinearLayout ... typically I have the order of the layouts and components in the order in which they appear on the screen from left to right, top to bottom. Are you saying I should not do this in this case, locating the xml for the LinearLayout before the TableLayout?

Comment: Yes. In **RelativeLayouts** you have to specify the referred components BEFORE they are referred by other components. You see, RelativeLayouts and LinearLayouts are **different beasts**. Sometimes it's good to use one kind, sometimes the other one. And sometimes a **combination** of both kinds.

Comment: Thanks, and by anchored to parentTop you mean: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`?

Comment: Thanks, using LinearLayout with weights, I've got what I want

Comment: That has not been my experience :)

Comment: But how much were you then satisfied, when you finally got it working as you like it? :)

Comment: You are correct, it is satisfying to get it to work correctly

Comment: It's the taste of development... ;) after all, it's always something creative!

Answer (score 2):

you can put both those layouts inside a relativelayout and use android:layout_centerInParent